# Change default view on removable drives

Tags: macos, finder, folders

How can I make Finder default to "list view" whenever browsing a removable drive (and it's subfolders)?

I need it to remember this preference even after the removable drive has been ejected and then remounted.

I'm running OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is on the external drive (HFS+, NTFS, FAT)?

Comment: The external drive is Mac OS Extended (Journaled). I appreciate your help!